# Cloning a package from github and use in spyder

Tags: python, git, github, anaconda, spyder

I would like to create a copy of a package on github that I can edit and use in spyder. I currently use the anaconda package manager  for my python packages.

Here are the steps that I have taken so far:

1. fork repo
2. clone repo onto my local directory

The package is called 'Nilearn'. I currently use anaconda and have installed nilearn via 'conda install nilearn'.

I would like to be able to use my own copy of nilearn inside spyder alongside nilearn. I have tried renamine the repo to nilearn_copy, but this doesn't appear to work.

If this is not possible or not the ideal solution, then please help suggest an alternative, I'm new to github and python.

Thanks a lot,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You need to open an IPython console, then run this command

```
In [1]: %cd /path/to/nilearn/parent
```

By this I mean that you to go with the `%cd` magic to the parent directory where `nilearn` is placed. After that you can run

```
In [2]: import nilearn
```

and that should import your local copy of `nilearn`.

---

Note: If you are planning to do changes to `nilearn` and want your changes to be picked up in the same console, you need to run these commands *before* the previous ones:

```
In [3]: %load_ext autoreload
In [4]: %autoreload 2
```