# How do I get code from Github into Spyder without using copy & paste

Tags: python, github, anaconda, spyder

Is there a way to copy code from github to spyder without using copy & paste?

Comment: technically, Spyder is an IDE to you don't copy your code there but you could use `git clone` to copy the github repo to your local machine and open the same in Spyder.

Comment: thank you. i don't understand why you say i can't copy code into Spyder. There is an editor tab where I type and run code.

Comment: Yes, I meant the complete repo with multiple files and not just the contents of a file.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889547/cloning-a-package-from-github-and-use-in-spyder

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia: can I use Spyder and let it autmatically load the code from GitHub?